# What does it mean "Within everything are meanings crystallized from the hues in the corona of that magnificent artwork-the human and her dignity."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading the following paragraph and I can't quite understand what the bold text means.

> And the depth of the inner world of a person has such rich potential
>   to develop, and the potential to keep developing dimensions within; a
>   complicated brain and a spirit with an elusive essence that evades
>   material measure; and then the perfectly harmonious relation of these
>   two phenomena-the physical and the spiritual together. . . mysterious
>   beings... **Within everything are meanings crystallized from the hues
>   in the corona of that magnificent artwork-the human and her dignity.**

It starts with "within everything" but continues with "are meanings crystallized" and that's the place I failed to understand since I don't know which type of grammar rule I should follow to decipher what it means.

Comment: That people write such tosh is always a mystery to me. What truly puzzles me is why anyone would want to read it. In fact that entire passage has almost no meaning at all. It is a vacuous statement expressed pretentiously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [inversion of word order](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/62213/10041).  A more straightforward way to say it would be:

> Meanings are crystallized within everything...

Look at the original, broken into units:

> 1[Within everything] 2[are 3[meanings] crystallized].

1 (*within everything*) is a grammatically optional prepositional phrase, 2 (*are crystallized*) is the verb phrase, and 3 (*meanings*) is the subject.  The rest of the sentence consists of other optional prepositional phrases.

Rearranged to normal (uninverted) word order, the whole sentence would be:

> Within everything, meanings are crystallized from the hues in the corona of that magnificent artwork - the human and her dignity.

The upshot is that the meanings contained inside everything are made realities for us by virtue of human glory.

Answer (score 0):

This passage in general is an abstract romanticizing of the metaphysical potential of the unity of the human spirit and its physical form. The bolded passage is a poetic expression that attempts to convey that transcendent glory. The **human and her dignity** refers to the divine aspect of each person, also described as a **magnificent artwork** (the artist being God? the Self? hard to say here). The **corona** is the crown, perhaps specifically intended to invoke the image of the sun's corona, because of the reference to its **hues**. Think of it like the [halo in old paintings of saints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_%28religious_iconography%29), representing the illumination of their spirit.  The **hues** of the corona represent the unspecified aspects of the holy light emanating from us. These hues **crystalize** as the meanings of all things. Crystalizing is the creation of a solid-state order from a dissolved liquid state.  In other words,

> all things have a meaning that is fluid, but various aspects of your
>   divine emanating spirit cause those meanings to take shape, and that's
>   a beautiful thing.