# Subject-auxiliary inversions not associated with questions

Tags: adverbs, auxiliary-verbs, subjects, subject-verb-inversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inversion in “only [adverb] have they”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/sentences-using-something-have-they)

Is there some rule governing the following, or similar, subject-auxiliary inversions (*"Rarely they do see the light of day", *"Never I have been so insulted")?

> *In fancy sit-down restaurants, you can order a large meal and halfway through the main course, take a little dead cockroach or a piece of glass out of your pocket and place it deftly on the plate. Jump up astonished and summon the headwaiter.* "**Never have I been so insulted**. *I could have been poisoned" you scream slapping down the napkin. You can refuse to pay and leave, or let the waiter talk you into having a brand new meal on the house for this terrible inconvenience.* ([link](http://www.urlr.us/eTags/1_001_ways_of_getting_everything_absolutely_FREE_A_FREE_guide_for_FREE_stuff__LoC29275.htm))
>
> **Rarely do they see the light of day***; it's generally judged to be in no one's commercial interest that they should. Just occasionally, however, like a seemingly dormant volcano, they explode into the open.* ([link](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/business/city--business-seismic-struggle-moves-the-earth-at-eurotunnel-1369059.html))

Comment: This is in no way a duplicate of the linked-to question.  This is clear because fronting with *only* in identical situations to the ones given by the OP clearly DOESN'T cause inversion: "*Only have I been so insulted*" (wrong) "*Only do they see the light of day*" (very, very wrong). This needs reopening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subject-Auxiliary Inversion with Adverb-Fronting is simply a [***Negative Polarity Item***](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) (NPI).

> ‘NPI’ is a term applied to lexical items, fixed phrases, or syntactic construction types that demonstrate unusual behavior around negation. NPIs might be words or phrases that occur only in negative-polarity contexts (*fathom, in weeks*) or have an idiomatic sense in such contexts (*not too bright, drink a drop*); or they might have a lexical affordance that only functions in such contexts (*need/dare* (*not*) *reply*); or a specific syntactic rule might be sensitive to negation, like Subject-Auxiliary Inversion with Adverb Fronting.

Subject-Auxiliary Inversion is OK with a fronted adverb that is a [Negative Trigger](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf). E.g, *ever* and *frequently* are not negative, but *never* is; hence:

- **Ever have I seen such a thing.*
- **Frequently have I seen such a thing.*
- *Never have I seen such a thing.*

Details of this and related constructions are available [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/anyquestions.pdf).

Comment: Can you explain exactly why OP's *"*Never I have been so insulted"* is **not** valid, whereas *"Never the twain shall meet"* is okay? Is it just that the latter is a "fossilised" archaic form?

Comment: Subject-verb inversion is normally obligatory with a preposed negative adverb. Yes, I think _Never the twain shall meet_ is a frozen form, so all bets are off.

Comment: Is Tolkien's usage [Théoden: "Simbelmynë. Ever has it grown on the tombs of my forebears."] [LOTR] archaic or an example of dramatic licence?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is such a rule, though it is not completely reliable. When a sentence starts with certain words that are both stressed and strongly limiting or negative, inversion is normally applied in (educated) writing, though not universally so. It expresses a certain rhetorical force. In casual writing, I believe it is less common. Usually words and phrases like *never, no...ever, rarely, no sooner, only, barely, scarcely, seldom* are involved. It is perhaps safer to look up a list of words that have this effect than apply it to a category, if you're not sure, because it doesn't work for all such words.

> Never had she met a man like Socrates.
>
> In no place but Athens had she ever known true happiness, and so there she stayed.
>
> In few other places had she ever been happy.
>
> Rarely are such bonds formed.
>
> No sooner had he married Xanthippe than her scourging tongue became manifest.
>
> Only in her did he find an opponent who could wear him down with words.
>
> Not only could she be voluble, but also scathing, when she so chose.
>
> Barely had he left the house when she would scream and call him back to finish chores.
>
> And scarcely had he finished one chore when she would make him do another.
>
> Seldom did he arrive on time.

This inversion probably has something to do with [pragmatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics) [focus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_%28linguistics%29) laid on the limiting or negating phrase; cf. ordinary focal inversion as in *this is Octavian, and him I have adopted as my son*.

There is also a broad, vague relation between negations and questions in English and other languages that may have something to do with this construction; consider how *do*-support is needed with questions and negations but not positive statements. But this connection is weak and speculative.

Comment: I think there's a "rule" that adverbs of frequency such as *rarely, never, seldom*, etc. tend to go before the verb. But that doesn't mean it's normally acceptable to splice a [pro]noun between the adverb and the verb. Of course, the main rule is "rules are meant to be broken", so we accept things like *"Never the twain shall meet"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Uh, sorry, but that rule has nothing to do with this.

Comment: "nothing to do with this"? How do you explain the fact that *"Never the twain shall meet"* (noun between adverb and verb) is just acceptable as *"Never shall the twain meet"* (normal positioning)?

Comment: If the exception proves the rule, do two exceptions prove there never was a rule?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Certainly, that part is relevant; but your rule about general placement of adverbs of frequency—this is about the inversion of subject and verb. Adverbs expressing frequency can go after the verb in many cases: *I see her often, I talk to her occasionally, I will never love her*. As to *never the twain shall meet,* that probably pre-dates the time when the rule about *never* etc. became firmly established.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The rule was not always as it is now. It developed, no doubt. And even now it is not reliable or universal.

Comment: It's quite reliable in that it requires a negative trigger to license the subject-auxiliary inversion with fronting. All of the examples above are negative: _none, no, few, rarely, barely, scarcely, seldom, only_ are all on [the list of Negative Triggers](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).