# "Not only should I" in declarative sentence

Tags: grammaticality

There is a phrase "Not only should I succeed but others should fail". And I saw it many times in similar structures that the order of words "should I" are as if they were in a questioning sentence. (In a declarative sentence the order is "I should")

Can anyone give me an explanation why that is?

Comment: This is not a question form.  "Not only are you tall, but also handsome."  "Not once did you fail."  "Never in a million years will you win this lottery."

Comment: See also [Subject-auxiliary inversions not associated with questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80644/subject-auxiliary-inversions-not-associated-with-questions), [Reason for Subject-Verb Inversion: Only in cases where A is B, shall the Company do X](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87416/reason-for-subject-verb-inversion-only-in-cases-where-a-is-b-shall-the-company/), and the questions linked from these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specific grammatical rule for this, but it is common to invert subject and verb when adverbs or adverb phrases are placed at the beginning of a sentence. See more 
here:

http://www.englishgrammar.org/inversion-subject-verb/#udVqaYOcOyIydwVs.99

and here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_sentence