# Inversion in English: "In no realm of life has..."

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

I'm a regular on your site and learning English. I read the newspaper on a regular basis.

Today I have come across this underlined sentence in the newspaper, it  sounds bit  odd to me.

> "*IN NO REALM OF LIFE HAS THE COVID 19 PANDEMIC WREAKED AS MUCH VISIBLE UPHEAVAL AS EDUCATION*"

Here "HAS" is not immediately followed by "WREAKED". I suppose it's an example of "inversion". Is that right?

Comment: In no way have you made an error in this supposition. But there are lots of other errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reason for Subject-Verb Inversion: Only in cases where A is B, shall the Company do X](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87416/reason-for-subject-verb-inversion-only-in-cases-where-a-is-b-shall-the-company): Preposing a negative adverbial of [metaphorical] place. John Lawler's answer.

Comment: If *wreaked* were moved to immediately after *has* in this exact construction, it would be extremely unidiomatic, if not considered ungrammatical.

Comment: @jason bassford sir can u pls elaborate it?

Comment: *In no realm of life **has wreaked** the COVID-19 pandemic as much visible upheaval as education.* All of the information is there, but it's been presented in an order that's almost never used and which makes it very difficult to parse. Even if it's arguably grammatical, I can't see anybody not correcting it.

Comment: IN NO REALM OF LIFE  THE COVID 19 PANDEMIC HAS WREAKED AS MUCH VISIBLE UPHEAVAL AS EDUCATION" Sir can i write it this way instead????

Comment: IN NO REALM OF LIFE HAS THE COVID 19 PANDEMIC WREAKED AS MUCH VISIBLE UPHEAVAL AS EDUCATION".  IN NO REALM OF LIFE  THE COVID 19 PANDEMIC HAS WREAKED AS MUCH VISIBLE UPHEAVAL AS EDUCATION".  Both are correct?????

Comment: Can you please quote the source of your example?