# Why does a negative adverbial phrase trigger inversion?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, negation, auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-inversion

When a negative adverb (or adverbial phrase) is placed at the beginning of a sentence, we exchange the normal placement of subject and verb.

Why is that?

Comment: Related and probable duplicate of at least one or another of: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/96620 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/62208 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1553 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/80644  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/88324 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95578

Comment: Not only do we invert the auxiliary in negative adverbial phrases, so too do we invert them in [a host of other circumstances detailed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-verb_inversion).