# The use of question formation in non-question phrases?

Tags: phrases, questions, errors, language-formation

I have read the following text some time ago:

> [...]
>     Only here can you enjoy dazzling entertainment, get the thrill
>   of your life on the exciting rides, and be face-to-face with some of
>   the most fascinating creatures on Earth.
>   [...]

Is *Only here can you* correct? I mean, it's not a question but it is formatted as it was. If it's correct, how, where and when can I use it?

Comment: I'm a little confused--what makes this a question formation? Are you talking about the use of "can you"?

Comment: Yeah, I mean... In formal speaking words can't just be inverted, can they?

Comment: Can they not be inverted? I beg to differ. Hit you with my *hyperbaton*, I shall.

Comment: Is that an early light-sabre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of subject-auxiliary inversion, all right. But that doesn't make it a question; there are other uses for that rule.

[One of these uses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80651/15299) is when a **negative** adverbial of time, space, or circumstance (as opposed, for instance, to adverbials of manner, purpose, or instrument) is preposed to the beginning of a sentence. In that case, following the preposed adverbial, the first auxiliary verb moves to follow it, and to precede the subject.

- *At no time has he ever been arrested.*  (negative adverbial of time)
- **At no time he has ever been arrested.*
  but
- **Without a knife did he manage to cut the bagel.* (negative adverb of instrument)
- *Without a knive he managed to cut the bagel.*

Answer (score 2):

This is just a reversal of word order, not a question.

> Only here can you ...

just means that "here" is the only place you can [do whatever].

If you were to use a different word order, the phrase would mean something different.

> Only here you can ...

would have the effect of turning "only" into a sentence adverb with the approximate meaning of "except" . . . .

Comment: … and “You can … only here” buries the lead, and “You can only … here” is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in thinking it a peculiar construction.

There is no problem if we leave out the locative and the limiting modifier:

**You can enjoy dazzling entertainment, get the thrill of your life on the exciting rides, and be face-to-face with some of the most fascinating creatures on Earth.**

Inserting the locative at the end of the sentence separates it too widely from the first verb:

**??You can enjoy dazzling entertainment, get the thrill of your life on the exciting rides, and be face-to-face with some of the most fascinating creatures on Earth here.**

Positioning it at the front is the answer:

**Here, you can enjoy dazzling entertainment, get the thrill of your life on the exciting rides, and be face-to-face with some of the most fascinating creatures on Earth.**

Adding various limiting modifiers seems idiosyncratic:

**Even here, you can enjoy dazzling entertainment, get the thrill of your life on the exciting rides, and be face-to-face with some of the most fascinating creatures on Earth.**

**Here alone can you enjoy dazzling entertainment, get the thrill of your life on the exciting rides, and be face-to-face with some of the most fascinating creatures on Earth.**

**Only here can you enjoy dazzling entertainment, get the thrill of your life on the exciting rides, and be face-to-face with some of the most fascinating creatures on Earth.**

Compare

**Nowhere else can you enjoy dazzling entertainment, get the thrill of your life on the exciting rides, and be face-to-face with some of the most fascinating creatures on Earth.**

and contrast

**Everywhere else, you can enjoy dazzling entertainment, get the thrill of your life on the exciting rides, and be face-to-face with some of the most fascinating creatures on Earth.**

I assume that constructions with these restricted conditions follow the pattern of J Lawler's negative-condition constructions. *Nowhere* and *nowhere else* are obviously closely related, for instance.