# Use of "did" in an affirmative sentence before subject

Tags: verbs, word-order, subject-verb-inversion, adverb-position, do-support

I wrote the following sentence in an article:

> Only in June it created repositories.

The editor corrected me:

> Only in June did it create repositories.

What's the explanation for "did" in this case? It doesn't sound like emphasis, because the following word is not a verb.

Comment: If you begin a sentence with a negative adverbial clause, as per your example, the word order is inverted and the auxiliary that you would use for an interrogative is inserted.

Comment: You began your sentence with *only*. That necessitates the use of the *did*. But you seem to understand this. What, then, is your question?

Comment: No, in fact I didn't know that. I found the explanation at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/inversion-in-only-adverb-have-they#62213 because of Martin's comment.

Comment: @rordigorgs No! because yours isn't a case of voluntary inversion as per the answers listed. It's mandatory - you *have* to do it in this situation.

Comment: @Araucaria I understand that from the answer that in this case the inversion is mandatory. "when the auxiliary comes before the subject and the rest of the verb phrase follows the subject (inversion is usually necessary)"

Comment: I've added a proper post now, hope it explains:) Any questions just ask though! :-)

Comment: @medica The OP rightly says that we use do for emphasis when this auxiliary occurs before the verb. As you say, it is occurring here because of only. However your assertion that the sentence must have inversion because they 'began the sentence only, is [not correct](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211005/inversion-by-only-in-a-passive-sentence) see both answers here. (Beware, the top-voted answer contains some completely incorrect information - as per Janus' comments as well as the second answer there - so please on no account make this a dupe of that question!)

Comment: @medica [This thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/inversion-in-only-adverb-have-they#62213) is also entertaining but doesn't explain - nor does the question ask - why the inversion occurs. As you'll see from both answers in the comments above, preposing with a restrictive *only* is not enough to trigger inversion.

Comment: @Martin Hmm, what's the negative adverbial there?

Comment: “I did everything I could to stop it from doing anything at all forever more; it took me two months of solid work at the end of the old year. My plan seemed to work: it didn’t do anything at all throughout the dead of winter, nor even in April or May. I thought we were finally free of the infernal daemon, having gone five months without trouble. Only in June it created repositories. I couldn’t believe it! I was simply beside myself with fury. Stupid daemons!”

Comment: @tchrist Yes, possible to use an *only* with a completely different meaning there. Maybe that's what rodrigorgs wanted to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Only in June **was it** creating repositories.
> 2. Only in June **it was** creating repositories. (ungrammatical)

In example (1) we see the auxiliary and subject change places. In example (2), the auxiliary and subject are the same as they would be in a normal sentence. It is ungrammatical.

> 3. Only in June **did it** create repositories.
> 4. Only in June **it** created repositories. (ungrammatical)

In sentence (3), again, we see subject auxiliary inversion. Sentence (4) has no auxiliary - this is because it has no inversion. However, it is ungrammatical.

Although we *can* insert auxiliaries for emphasis, the use of *do* is obligatory in the sentences above. It is not about emphasis. It is because we need to ***invert*** the subject and auxiliary verb. They have to change places. We can't do this if there is no auxiliary, so in sentence (3) we use the 'dummy' auxiliary *DO* so that we can create an inversion. Note that the main verb *create* can't be used for inversion:

- Only in June **created it** repositories. (ungrammatical)

Moving *only* to the front of a sentence will trigger subject auxiliary inversion in main clauses under certain conditions. Here are some examples:

- Only if we've received the papers can we release the prisoner.
- *Only if we've received the papers we can release the prisoner. (wrong)
- Only after the concert did I notice Pavarotti in the back row.
- *Only after the concert I saw Pavarotti in the back row. (wrong)
- Only in extreme circumstances did they steal.
- *Only in extreme circumstances they stole. (wrong)
- Only in the houses of parliament will you find this many cads.
- *Only in the houses of parliament you will find this many cads. (wrong)

The grammatical sentences have certain features in common:

- i) These sentences all have subordinate preposition phrases which occur before the main clause (phrases with *if, before, after, during* and so forth)
- ii) These prepositions are always prepositions of time, place or condition.
- iii) The head preposition in each case is being modified by *only*.
- iv) *Only* must have the sense of *not except* in such examples.

When these conditions apply, subject auxiliary inversion will apply. Notice that although *only* modifies the subordinate phrase, the inversion occurs in the main clause. The subject auxiliary inversion does not occur in the subordinate clauses.

**The Original Poster's Question**

The main clause in the Original Poster question is a version of the canonical (normal) clause:

- it created repositories.

However, this main clause is fronted by a temporal preposition phrase *in June*. This preposition phrase *in June* is being modified by the adverb *only*. This requires us to invert the subject and the auxiliary verb in the main clause. As we previously noted, the main clause is:

- it created repositories.

There is no auxiliary in this clause - so we need to use the dummy auxiliary, *do* for the inversion:

- **did it** create repositories.

This gives us the sentence:

> - Only in June did it create repositories.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: And we can't just invert "it created" to "Only in June created it repositories" because in present-day English we generally don't invert verbs that aren't auxiliaries, so *did* has to be press-ganged in to do the job.

Comment: @JonHanna Thanks,  is that better? - or worse?

Comment: I think so. I myself had started to write something that turned into such a convoluted mess that I deleted it to start again and found that you'd given this answer in the meantime covering everything I had intended to bar that point.

Comment: You've had me delete two or three over the last couple of days ;) But often glad you got there first - cuz I hadn't thought of most of the fiddly bits.

Comment: Yes, and it can be hard to decide just how fiddly to get, combined with the relative haste of answers compared to other types of writing often leading to Pascal's apology; "I made this very long, because I did not have the leisure to make it shorter".