# "No sooner do I sit..." Why does this have "do I" when it's not a question?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-inversion

I have no idea what kind of grammar this is.

> No sooner **do I** sit at the foot of my bed than one of the beginning trainees comes to the door.

How can they use *do I* in that sentence and still not end it with a question mark?.

Comment: When certain negative adverbs are moved to the beginning of the sentence, they trigger subject-auxiliary inversion the same way questions do. For instance, _Never have I seen such a thing; Nowhere can this be found._

Comment: oh ! that make sense ty !

Answer (score 0):

In a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/345420/no-sooner-do-i-sit-why-does-this-have-do-i-when-its-not-a-question#comment799013_345420), John Lawler wrote:

> When [certain negative adverbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121843/15299) are moved to the beginning of the sentence, they trigger [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80651/15299) the same way questions do. For instance, *Never have I seen such a thing; Nowhere can this be found.*

Comment: The reason I made it a comment was that I've answered this question [multiple times before](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+subject+auxiliary+inversion+adverb+negative). Though nobody ever bothers looking. So I added links to some of them here, where there's room.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks very much. I was trying to make something that could be more easily searched than comments. The links are appreciated.