# Not till (sentence) + do ( sentence)

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

Can someone explain the structure of the following sentence?

> Not till he got home did he realise that he had lost his mobile.

Why we are doing inversion here ?

Comment: I am sorry for tag

Comment: I assume you wrote the sentence, since it has no attribution. So why did _you_ use inversion?

Comment: No i was doing practice and came across this sentence in book

Comment: If you are doing a practice surely there is some sort of explanantion in the book. What part did you not understand? You need to show some research.

Comment: Don't pay attention to explanations in practice books. Indeed, many of the sentences in English practice books are made up by non-native speakers who don't understand English grammar (or often, English). So many of the sentences are themselves ungrammatical. In this case the inversion is licensed by the fact that [the inverted material is negative and negates the main clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/121843/15299) -- i.e, he **didn't** realize he'd lost his mobile until he reached home.

Comment: @John Lawler thanks i got it. Could you write this in answer section so that i am accept it