# Only...did I... / Only...I

Tags: do-support, only

1. Only after reading it carefully several times **did I begin to make** sense of the poem.
2. Only after reading it carefully several times **I began making** sense of the poem.

I know that the first one is correct but I do not understand why.  Other than sounding strange, why is the second one incorrect?  Thank you very much!

Comment: No. 1 is grammatical, 2 is ungrammatical. When a negative adverbial phrase (_only_ is a negative trigger) [of the right kind](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/101123/15299) is preposed, the sentence [undergoes subject-auxiliary inversion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80651/15299), if the negative scope extends to it. Since you hadn't begun to make sense of it until after reading it several times (that's the scope of _only_, extending to the clause), the inversion is obligatory. Oh, and, by the way, "ungrammatical" **means** "sounding strange to a syntactically trained native speaker".

Comment: This question has been asked, and answered, [20+ times](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/62208?lq=1) by now. Please use the site search before asking.