# Usage of "Can" as a sentence

Tags: word-order, subject-verb-inversion

I have seen the following paragraph in a sample IELTS writing test but don't understand its grammatical structure. Why is it in question format but affirmative?

> To conclude, some say that we can get to know a country and its customs from the internet or TV, others believe that by going to those countries **can we gain a deeper understanding**.

Comment: Does “By their works shall you know them” also confuse you, or does that one make sense? It's the same sort of inversion.

Comment: The sentence is not idiomatic.  If it was worded as "... believe that *only* by going ..." it would be idiomatic.

Comment: Looks like someone left out an 'only': "others believe that **only** by going to those countries can we gain a deeper understanding."

Comment: Yes; an 'only' makes semantic sense and is a necessary inversion-trigger here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that an "only" is missing from the example.  As a native speaker the general rule here had me puzzled for a bit, and I tried to think of other examples where this inversion happens.   Then I recalled some song lyrics from the musical "Oklahoma":

> Never have I once looked back to sigh
>   Over the romance behind me
>   Many a new day will dawn
>   Before I do

Certain "negative" adverbials at the beginning of a sentence or phrase trigger the inversion of the usual order of subject and auxiliary verb.  For example,

> We can gain an understanding only by .... ->  Only by ... can we gain an understanding.

You might want to check out [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/inversion-in-only-adverb-have-they) for a more complete explanation.