# What is the grammatical point of "have psychologists developed" instead of "psychologists have developed"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

There was a reading test for my university entrance exam which contained this sentence: "Only in the past hundred years, though, have psychologists developed objective techniques" with "have psychologists developed" blanked and mangled as selections. The source is [here](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21228416-200-memory-from-sense-to-storage/) if you google it.

My Question is about the grammatical tricky point of this form, why not saying "psychologists have developed".

Comment: Your sentence contains an example of _subject-auxiliary inversion_. There is a good answer to a similar question here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/inversion-in-only-adverb-have-they