# Only if __ "can you" __

Tags: grammar

> "You can __ only if __."
>
> "Only if __ can you __."

Why does the word order change to "can you" in the latter sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inversion in "only \[adverb\] have they"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/inversion-in-only-adverb-have-they)