# Little did I suspect that she would sign a new contract.(inversion)

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Why is it inversion? We use DID after the word LITTLE. If I see another example,I'll understand .So-Not until we saw our kids with our own eyes did we believe they were really safe and sound- in that case DID stay after -we saw...And It's wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inversion in "only \[adverb\] have they"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/inversion-in-only-adverb-have-they) ('Little did they ...' is one of many such constructions, using inversion after negative/restrictive expressions, listed in Daniel's accepted answer.)