# 'Only recently were they' and 'Only recently they were'

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, negation, only

1. Only recently (in February 1998) women’s ice hockey was incorporated into the Olympic Winter Games, while men’s ice hockey has been a fixed event ever since the first Winter Games started in 1924.
2. Only recently (in February 1998) was women’s ice hockey incorporated into the Olympic Winter Games, while men’s ice hockey has been a fixed event ever since the first Winter Games started in 1924.
3. Only recently (in February 1998) that women’s ice hockey was incorporated into the Olympic Winter Games, while men’s ice hockey has been a fixed event ever since the first Winter Games started in 1924.

Out of these three, which one is correct? Why? And why are the others wrong?

---

**Note:** Some users have stated in comments underneath that example (3) is ungrammatical, but it's not clear why. In addition one established user said that (1) was clumsy but meant the same as (2), the difference was stylistic. Another one, however, said that (1) and (2) had different meanings. A third mentioned that negative *only* licensed the subject-auxiliary inversion in (2), and that it was an NPI. Whilst helpful, these do not properly explain which of (1)-(3) are acceptable and why.

Comment: Version #3 is syntactically invalid (could be fixed by adding ***It was...*** at the start). I think version #1 is clumsy - this is a context where we'd normally invert subject/object (***was hockey*** rather than ***hockey was***). But that's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is a difference in meaning between (1) and (2). The difference semantic as well as stylistic. (Although (1) definitely requires a comma).

Comment: This question is clearly about the English language. The close reason seems bizarre to me.

Comment: Note that the inversion is licensed by the negative _only_. Such inversion is an NPI.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore: Now I'll have to vote to reopen the very question I was the first to VTC! I don't recognise any significant difference in meaning between #1: *Only recently was dueling declared illegal* and  2: *Only recently dueling was declared illegal*. Maybe #1 is more likely in contexts primarily focused on ***dueling*** (*before* it was banned), and #2 is more likely in contexts primarily focused on ***banning*** various things. But that's a matter of style and nuance rather than different meanings. So now I'm voting to reopen simply to learn about any supposed difference!

Comment: (My VTC was for migration to ELL. Obviously no-one else's was! :)

Comment: @JohnLawler Fumblefingers And, in fact, it’s even more complex than that. The SAI allows the exceptive negation to scope right over the rest of the clause, which is in its entirety now an NPI environment. But it can’t/doesn’t scope over the clause without SAI, and the rest of that clause is not an NPI environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inversion in 'only \[adverb\] have they'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/inversion-in-only-adverb-have-they).

Comment: NPI strength is shown by say _seldom_; 'Seldom ice hockey was regarded so highly' is awful. But I feel that 'Only recently' can have the sense 'Even in the recent past' as well as 'At no other times than in the recent past', which complicates things.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Exactly so. And in the *not long ago* sense, there is no negation of the larger clause.